# calculating the prediction ratio for a logistic regression

Tags: r, lm

I want to calculate the prediction ratio

I have predicted a logistic regression, and I also have a dataset of the observation of another variable.

I want to calculate the correctly predicted ratio.

I have recorded the prediction like this

```
glm9 = glm(v172 ~ age, family=binomial (link="logit"), data=france)

pre10<-predict(glm9, germany, type="terms")
prediction <- ifelse (pre10 >=1, 1, 0)

prediction
   0    1 
 305 5039
```

The results I have predicted is a value, but the observation value is
a variable in a dataframe

I want to have a table that looks like this:

```
  0    1
0 182 63

1 24  32
```

Comment: Can you show a small reproducible example..  It is not clear where your error is

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure how to show the example?

Comment: Your description is not clear.  are you looking for confusion matrix?

Comment: i.e. `library(caret); confusionMatrix(+(france$v172 >=1), prediction)`

Comment: Hi, sorry for the confusion. I just don't know how to calculate the correctly predicted ratio based on the glm ()

Comment: `prediction <- predict(glm9, france, type = "response")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want something like this.  I used mtcars because I didn't have your data.

```
glm9 <- glm(am ~ cyl, family=binomial (link="logit"), data=mtcars)
prob <- predict(glm9, type = "response")
prediction <- ifelse(prob < 0.5, 0, 1)
with(mtcars, table(am, prediction)
```

Which gives:

```
  prediction
     0  1
  0 16  3
  1  5  8
```